# Как использовать интервал в fsolve?

Tags: python

Я передаю в функцию приблизительные параметры. Как можно сделать, чтобы передавать интервалы?

```
`opt.fsolve(self.ClambCalculate, 5,2)

    def ClambCalculate(self, Clamb):
        C = Clamb[0]
        kLamb = Clamb[1]
        #Расчет
```

`

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Интервал — это обычно два числа, вот и передавайте два числа куда вам надо. Какое отношение к вопросу имеет показанный вами код?

Comment: @andreymal, Мне нужно чтобы fsolve считало в пределах. Как это сделать? или есть ещё другие методы подбора, чтобы был интеграл?

Comment: Что такое fsolve?

Comment: @andreymal, находит корни (нули) системы нелинейных уравнений

Comment: Откуда этот fsolve взялся?

Comment: @andreymal, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html отсюда